# Problema com consulta join com 5 tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, join

Boa noite,

Estou a tentar fazer um join a 5 tabelas para me buscar a informação de maneira que não me está a retornar dados alguns.

Código

```
SELECT * FROM estabelecimentos 
INNER JOIN estabelecimentos_anexos
    ON estabelecimentos_anexos.id_mae = estabelecimentos.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM avaliacoes)
    ON avaliacoes.estabelecimento_id = estabelecimentos.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM estabelecimentos_anexos)
    ON estabelecimentos_anexos.id_mae = estabelecimentos.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS id_post FROM posts)
    ON posts.estabelecimento_id = estabelecimentos.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROUND((SUM(pontos) / COUNT(*)), 1) FROM avaliacoes)
    ON avaliacoes.estabelecimento_id = estabelecimentos.id  
WHERE estabelecimentos.activo = 1
```

Comment: Qual a estrutura das suas tabelas? Já considerou montar um exemplo no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? De todo modo, creio que [um dos] seu problema é que as *subqueries* utilizadas não estão ganhando um apelido de modo que possam ser referenciadas no `ON` (mais detalhes [nessa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10493512/520779)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você faz uma *subquery* dentro de uma junção tipo:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM avaliacoes)
    ON avaliacoes.estabelecimento_id = estabelecimentos.id
```

Há dois problemas com ela:

1. A *subquery* vai contar **todas** as linhas da tabela, não só aquelas onde `avaliacoes.estabelecimento_id = estabelecimentos.id`;
2. A junção não será feita, pois na cláusula `ON` não há referência alguma para o resultado da *subquery*.

Pelo que pude presumir da sua intenção observando o código, provavelmente o que você está tentando fazer é algo como:

```
INNER JOIN (    SELECT estabelecimento_id as id, COUNT(*) AS count
                FROM avaliacoes
                WHERE estabelecimento_id = estabelecimentos.id
                GROUP BY estabelecimento_id
           ) apelido1
    ON apelido1.id = estabelecimentos.id
```

Isso precisaria ser feito para cada *subquery* dentro de uma junção.